# How to disable expand area for pyramid chart in canvasjs

Tags: canvasjs

[image: https://canvasjs.com/javascript-charts/pyramid-chart-area-represents-value/]

when I click on pyramid chart then it will be expand, how to disable expand area of pyramid chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [explodeOnClick](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/data/explode-on-click/) to false to disable exploding of sections in CanvasJS funnel / pyramid chart. Setting [interactivityEnabled](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/interactivity-enabled/) property to false, as mentioned by [user14299292](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63952083/5808897) will remove complete interactivity of chart - doesn't show toolTip aswell. Below is an example.

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  data: [{
  type: "pyramid",
  explodeOnClick: false, //**Change it to true
  dataPoints: [
    {  y: 10, indexLabel:"Research & Design" },
    {  y: 12, indexLabel:"Manufacturing" },
    {  y: 8, indexLabel:"Marketing" },
    {  y: 8, indexLabel: "Shipping" },
    {  y: 15, indexLabel:"Retail" }
  ]
}]
});

chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var  chart =  new  CanvasJS.Chart("container",
{
 .
 .
 interactivityEnabled: false,
 .
 .
});
chart.render();
```